# Stuck at terminal login (tty1) after using 'killall gdm'

Tags: 12.04, gnome, command-line, gui, gdm

So I am running a theme on gnome and it froze, so I used `killall gdm` to kill it. After this it took me to a full-screen terminal which I can not get out of. It tells me to login, which I do, and then it says:

```
Last login Sun Jun 3 11:19:32 PDT 2012 on tty4
Welcome to ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

22 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

casey@casey-computer:~$
```

I want to just get back to my desktop and start using my computer again. What should I do? What code should I type?

Answer (score 3):

The following command should help:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

If you don't have root (sudo) permissions you might have to login as root instead and run the command without the sudo.

Comment: And how do I do that, as I said i'm very new to ubuntu

Comment: You just type it after you log in and get the command line the
(after this appears: casey@casey-computer:~$)

Comment: what do i type? root or sudo?

Comment: the exact command in the grey box after you log in

Comment: alright I think i figured it out, i just typed "sudo reboot" thanks man

Comment: @Purplerob The `root` account is disabled by default in Ubuntu (and enabling it is [quite possible but neither supported nor recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)). If someone is the only user on their Ubuntu system, they will be configured as an administrator and can run commands with `sudo`. Additional users may also be given that power. If you don't have it, you can log on as a user who does, but logging on as `root` will not succeed.

Comment: @casey If you don't want to accept this answer, you can [create your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) describing what you did to solve the problem, i.e., running `sudo reboot`. (By the way,`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` will also cleanly shut down and reboot an Ubuntu system when pressed in a text-based console.) You can even accept your answer (after waiting 24 hours after writing it). This will make clear, for the benefit of others, what method you used (since comments are subject to editing and/or deletion at any time by moderators).